# deleting image using modal id

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that shows the photos of the user and in that modal that has the photo has a trash icon for the user to delete the photo, and as soon as he clicks the trash, another modal appears asking if he is sure he wants to delete the photo.
And confirming the photo is deleted.
the problem is that you are always deleting the first photo, you are not deleting the photo that is in the modal.
if I id in any photo in the middle of the gallery and click, this photo opens in the modal, the photo I chose, but when trying to delete, always delete the first photo of the gallery

modalgallery.js

```
    $(function() {
        $('.pop').on('click', function() {
            $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-img-url'));
            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
        });     
    });
```

modalconfirmedelete.js

```
    $(function() {
        $('.pop2').on('click', function() {

            $('#delete').modal('show');   

        });     
    });
```

views.py

```
def delete(request, id):
    photos = Photo.objects.get(id=id)
    photos.delete()
    return redirect('sistema_perfil')

def perfil(request):
    photos_list =  Photo.objects.filter(user=request.user.pk)
    usuario = Usuario.objects.all()
    form = UsuarioForm()
    data = {'usuario': usuario, 'form': form, 'photos': photos_list}
    return render(request, 'perfil.html', data)
```

perfil.html

```
     {% for photo in photos %}

              <a class="pop" href="#"  data-img-url="{{ photo.file.large.url}}"><img src="{{ photo.file.medium.url}}"class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="200"> </a>

              <!-- Modal Gallery-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">              
                    <div class="modal-body">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">X</span></button>
                          <img src="{{ photo.file.large.url}}" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
                          <a class="pop2" href="{% url 'delete' photo.id %}" ><img src="{% static 'svg/delete.svg' %}" width="20" height="20" alt="">Deletar </a>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">              
                    <div class="modal-body">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">X</span></button>

                                      <h2>Tem certeza que deseja deletar essa foto: </h2>
                                      <a href="{% url 'delete' photo.id %}" type="button" class="btn bg-danger text-white js-upload-photos">
                                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Deletar
                                            </a>


                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
              </div>


        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute of your delete modals are not unique, so `$('#delete')` always refers to the same modal.

You could create unique ids for your models and add a data attribute to your `.pop2` button. Something like this should work:

perfil.html

```
{% for photo in photos %}

    ...
    <a class="pop2" data-target="delete-{{ for.counter }}" href="{% url 'delete' photo.id %}" >
    ...
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete-{{ for.counter }}">
    ...
```

modalconfirmedelete.js

```
$(function() {
    $('.pop2').on('click', function() {

        $($(event.delegateTarget).data('target')).modal('show');   

    });     
});
```

On a side note, I would strong recommend to change your `delete` view to only perform the deletion on `POST` requests:

views.py

```
def delete(request, id):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
    photos = Photo.objects.get(id=id)
    photos.delete()
    return redirect('sistema_perfil')
```

Instead of `<a href="{% url 'delete' photo.id %}"` you would use a form and a button :

perfil.html

```
<form action="{% url 'delete' photo.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<submit class="btn bg-danger">...
```

Comment: the problem is that being in hfrj of his photo.id he deletes before going into modal